# PHP fwrite new line

Tags: php

I'm trying to write username and password to a new line in a txt file.
The output should be something like this in the txt file.
I know this is not very secure but its just for learning purposes

```
Sebastian   password
John        hfsjaijn
```

This is what i have so far

```
if(isset($_GET['register'])) //  
{
    $user  = $_GET['username'];
    $password=$_GET['password'];
    $fh = fopen("file.txt","a+");
    fwrite($fh,$user."\n"); //write to txtfile
    fwrite($fh,$password."\n"); // write to txtfile
    fclose($fh);
}
```

EDIT: Here's the solution for me:

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
   $user  = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'].PHP_EOL;
   $fh = fopen("file.txt","a+");
   fwrite($fh,$user." ".$password); //write to txtfile
  
   fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: You're writing a line break after you write your user. Try doing `fwrite($fh, $user . "," . $password . "\n");` Like this you will get a comma seperated value in your txt file like this: `userName,Password`

Comment: @ToonCasteele That doesnt work. The output is now John,passwordusername,passoword

Comment: Then it's likely that the application reading that data doesn't recognize `\n` as a line break, try `\r\n` instead, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline and http://docs.php.net/manual/reserved.constants#constant.php-eol

Comment: Like @DinoBabu said: use `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\n"`, that ought to do it

Comment: You aren't meant to [edit] your question to write your resolution in it.  That is what answering is for. @Dyna

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) which produces `\r\n` or `\n`

```
$data = 'my data' . PHP_EOL . 'my data';
$fp = fopen('my_file', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

// File output

```
my data
my data
```

Comment: Thanks this kind of work , but  now username and password is not on the same line

Answer (score 1):

You append a newline to both the username *and* the password, i.e. the output would be something like

```
Sebastian
password
John
hfsjaijn
```

use `fwrite($fh,$user." ".$password."\n");` instead to have them both on one line.
Or use [fputcsv()](http://docs.php.net/fputcsv) to write the data and `fgetcsv()` to fetch it. This way you would at least avoid encoding problems like e.g. with `$username='Charles, III';`

...i.e. setting aside all the things that are wrong about storing plain passwords in plain files and using _GET for this type of operation (use _POST instead) ;-)

Comment: There's no newline after the password.

Comment: right, there also a typo there. I'd suggest using fputcsv() anyway ...if anything...

Answer (score 1):

```
fwrite($handle, "<br>"."\r\n");
```

Add this under

```
$password = $_POST['password'].PHP_EOL;
```

this.          .

Answer (score 0):

How about you store it like this?
Maybe in username:password format, so

```
sebastion:password123
anotheruser:password321
```

Then you can use `list($username,$password) = explode(':',file_get_contents('users.txt'));`
to parse the data on your end.