# How to add data in new line of the file in php

Tags: php, html, line, each

How to add each of data in new line instead aside.

```
$file = fopen('C:\Users\ibm\Desktop\n=xD\Projekt1\1.txt', "a");
$dodaj = $dod_tytulu."  ". $dod_opisu."$dod_gatunku\n";
fwrite($file,$dodaj);
fclose($file)
;
```

This is a way of adding new data but in parallel instead upright.

Comment: What's the output? HTML?

Comment: Welcome to SO.Your question is not understandable. Please add information, for example current output and expected output. Visit the [help] - for example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL` which produces `\r\n` or `\n`

Comment: [older Stack Overflow Thread about this topic][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130289/php-fwrite-new-line

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
$file = fopen('C:\Users\ibm\Desktop\n=xD\Projekt1\1.txt', "a");
$dodaj = $dod_tytulu."  ". $dod_opisu."$dod_gatunku".PHP_EOL;
fwrite($file,$dodaj);
fclose($file);
```