# Remove line break while writing to text file in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to write a value of a random ID received from a third party website by JSON decode. I am using following code.

```
$myFile = "trID.txt";
$myFileLink = fopen($myFile, 'a');
$newContents = $TrID."\n";
fwrite($myFileLink, $newContents);
fclose($myFileLink);
```

The problem is it is giving a line break above every entry due to unknown reason. If I use 'w' instead of 'a', the file remains blank. Basically i will prefer 'w' as i need to overwrite each entry. The result file is like this.

345435454545

454545454455

345454354354

676767676767

I was suggested [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string) link but it does not remove white space above the ID value while writing to the file. Still getting blank file if i use 'w' in code because first value is always a line break.

Comment: Is $TrID from the JSON (after decode) ?

Comment: Resolution edited into question at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15130289/2943403

Comment: This does not solve. I need to remove line break above the value written. If I use 'w' in the code, the file remains blank, as first value is line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myFile = "trID.txt";
$myFileLink = fopen($myFile, 'a');
$newContents = $TrID;
fwrite($myFileLink, $newContents);
fclose($myFileLink);
```

You Can Remove only `."\n"`  in your Code

Comment: Yes $TrID comes from json decode. It is adding line break above the value written. removing \n joins all the IDs.

Comment: How do you want to print???

Comment: $TrID."\t" also use "\t" set horizontal tab